# add lock screen above alert view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I have Timeout screen. if UIAlertView is displaying on screen and application is ideal for some time  then lock screen appears, so issue is that lock screen is going below the alert view

[image]

Comment: try to add lockscreen in alertview . as i think

Comment: alertview with lockscreen will appear above existing alertview??

Comment: yes why not . add your view in alertview and then after you show alert.

Comment: i tryed but alertiew width is not occupying the my view size, i want full screen view

Comment: so try it add that view in window . i hope you get success .

Comment: Not don't try and add your view to the alertView. The UIAlertView is meant be used as is and you shouldn't be messing with the view hierarchy, this is just going to get your app rejected from the app store. Checkout the section marked as **Subclassing Note** in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html you shouldn't be adding a view to `UIAlertView`. If you want to do this then use a custom alert view. Here is an example of one https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved by changing window level property

window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1;

Answer (score 0):

Hide alertView and display Timeout screen. After timeout screen dismissal display alertView again.